# Weird syntax Error while Inserting data to PostgreSQL using Entity Framework

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-6, npgsql

Context:

```
    public MyContext() : base("POSTGRE_TestDB") //For PostreSQL
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    public DbSet<testModel> testcase { get; set; }
```

Model:

```
[Table("test_table")]
public class testModel
{
    [Key]
    //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string test_name { get; set; }
}
```

My code:

```
var test = new testModel();
test.id = 10;
test.test_name = "test";
            try
            {
                //_context.Entry(test).State = EntityState.Added;
                _context.testcase.Add(test);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }catch(...){...}
```

Querying the same database is working as usual.
Problem comes when inserting the row.
Error:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> 
System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> 
Npgsql.NpgsqlException: ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "RETURNING"
```

I am not sure what's wrong with the syntax exactly of Postgres because of the EF. Can anybody tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: Postgres should have recorded the query in its log, if the `RETURNING` string is part of a query.  Could you look in the Postgres logs for the error message and query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the logs of Postgres. The insert statement executed by entity framework was :

```
INSERT INTO "public"."test_table"("test_name") VALUES ('test') RETURNING "id"
```

Nothing is wrong with this generated command by entity framework. The Postgres I am using is 8.0.1 which I guess doesn't support RETURNING keyword. 
I will have to find some way to exclude RETURNING from the insert query.

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.0.1 is extremely ancient by now - Entity Framework will simply not work well against it.

Comment: @shay  Yeah I know. The EF search queries are working as usual. But the insertion queries need to be hard coded.